# I made model migrations during development. Now production database can't detect changes

Tags: django, migration

So I made a few changes to a few models, then made migrations to make sure everything worked locally. Local database is SQLite

Then I pushed to github, and then pulled it onto my Digital Ocean VPS. VPS using postgresql

Then I tried running makemigrations and it's not detecting any changes. 
Despite all the files showing the new changes.

Did I screw up by making migrations locally?
How do I fix this?

Comment: Best practice is to commit the migrations files with github and not to run `makemigrations` in the server.

Comment: @ruddra is correct. and I think probably you already commit `migrations` files, so try basically run `python manage.py migrate` on yout digital ocean server.

Comment: so I'm not supposed to migrate on the VPS server? So just migrate locally, then upload to the server?

Comment: Sounds like you're confusing `makemigrations` and `migrate`. You `makemigrations` once, and commit the resulting migration files as part of your source code. You then need to `migrate` each server independently.

Comment: i mean run it on your vps.

Comment: OK Thanks @KevinChristopherHenry & tim. I think I understand what you mean now. But before posting this, I migrated locally, and then migrated on the server, and it has completed screwed up the database. Some models aren't showing new changes and some are coming up with "column xyz does not exist" errors. Do I have to delete the postgres database on my server and restart?

Comment: Maybe. If the data is important you could try to massage the schema into shape manually. Apparently you did something in your experimentation that put the state of the database out of sync with the migrations history. So starting from scratch might be the easiest thing.

Comment: @KevinChristopherHenry - I started from scratch again. New droplet. Everything worked fine. Just now I made a new change to a model, and this time, I `makemigration` locally, then immediately committed to git, and pulled to VPS. Then `migrate` on VPS. And again, the changes aren't reflected in the schema. Everything else was updated successfully. Is there a setting I forgot to set?

Comment: The only relevant setting is that it's in your `INSTALLED_APPS`. What did the output of `migrate` say? What's the output of [`showmigrations`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#showmigrations)? Do you have multiple `DATABASES`? Did you specify the database with `migrate`? This isn't something that can be debugged over StackOverflow comments, so I suggest you do as much research and debugging as you can, and if you can't figure it out edit your question with all the details or post a new one.

Comment: @KevinChristopherHenry It turns out I have to restart gunicorn to pick up any changes I make to the site. LOL

Answer (score 1):

Since you have already  done makemigrations locally and pushed to the production **.Since you haven't change the model so makemigrations cannot detect changes.**
But if you change model field in production and try to do makemigrations it will detect changes.

As stated by [@rudrra](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2696165/ruddra) Best practice not to run makemigrations in the server. In addition , Always make  changes to environment variables only  in production files.

But incase if you need to make changes  model field in production files always pull production file to local.(update local files)

from the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/migrations/) regarding migrations

- **migrate**, which is responsible for applying and unapplying migrations.
- **makemigrations**, which is responsible for creating new migrations based on the changes you have made to your models.

Comment: I'm not quite understanding your answer

Comment: I mean do makemigrants locally and push code to server and do migrate in server